# Poor performance on Window Lag function for large Spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a very large spark dataframe where we wish to create a lag column:

```
lag_df = df.withColumn('lag',func.lag(df['id'],1)
                       .over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('id')))

+---+----+
| id| lag|
+---+----+
|  1|null|
|  2|   1|
|  3|   2|
|  4|   3|
|  5|   4|
   .    .
   .    .
```

I found that the above ends up running on a single executor. This is fine for small dataframes, but it is not scalable at all. ***We can't use the paritionBy***, so is there a different way to improve the scalability of this task?

Comment: You didn’t define a partition !

Comment: Partition the data based on the id. The new code will be like: ```lag_df = df.withColumn('lag',func.lag(df['id'],1)
                       .over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('id')))```

Comment: @NikhilBaby, this is the dilemma. If I partition by id, then the lag column will be filled with nulls.

Comment: @eliasah, How would I go about partitioning without introducing null values in the lag column?

Comment: your requirement suggests that you will have to execute the lag function in one executor because in distributed system how will you tell that the partition in one executor is the previous or later partition of another partition in another executor? thats possible when you partition data so that the last row of each partition is duplicated in the next partition. so you will have to write a custom partitioner for that